# "Because I was not" vs. "For not being"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> I was angry with her **because I was not invited** to her party.

vs

> I was angry with her **for not being invited** to her party.

Is the second sentence meaningful/grammatical. 
If yes, do these sentences have the same meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both grammatical but the meaning is not quite the same.

The second sentence has an elliptical subject. That is, the subject of "being" is implied. You have to look further back in the sentence to find it.

Most of the time, if not every time, the implied subject in this structure is the **target** of the emotion. So in this case that would be **her**.

Therefore, you're angry with her because **she** wasn't invited to her party (I guess another woman's or girl's party). As you can already guess, this doesn't make much sense because a person doesn't decide whether or not they're invited to a party.

So the sentence you want is the first one.

---

Here are a few examples of the second structure so you can see how the implied subject works:

> I was angry with her for not inviting me to her party. *[She didn't invite me.]*
>
> I was angry with the kids for lying to my face. *[The kids lied to my face.]*
>
> The kids were angry with their parents for grounding them. *[The parents grounded the children.]*

Comment: But isn't her the object here?

Comment: It is a kind of complement, but that doesn't stop it from becoming the subject of the embedded part.